# LSTM's expected hidden state dimensions doesn't take batch size into account

Tags: python-3.x, lstm, pytorch, batchsize

I have this decoder model, which is supposed to take batches of sentence embeddings (batchsize = 50, hidden size=300) as input and output a batch of one hot representation of predicted sentences:

```
class DecoderLSTMwithBatchSupport(nn.Module):
        # Your code goes here
        def __init__(self, embedding_size,batch_size, hidden_size, output_size):
            super(DecoderLSTMwithBatchSupport, self).__init__()
            self.hidden_size = hidden_size
            self.batch_size = batch_size
            self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=embedding_size,num_layers=1, hidden_size=hidden_size, batch_first=True)
            self.out = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
            self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

        def forward(self, my_input, hidden):
            print(type(my_input), type(hidden))
            output, hidden = self.lstm(my_input, hidden)
            output = self.softmax(self.out(output[0]))
            return output, hidden

        def initHidden(self):
            return Variable(torch.zeros(1, self.batch_size, self.hidden_size)).cuda()
```

However, when I run it using:

```
decoder=DecoderLSTMwithBatchSupport(vocabularySize,batch_size, 300, vocabularySize)
decoder.cuda()
decoder_input=np.zeros([batch_size,vocabularySize])
    for i in range(batch_size):
        decoder_input[i] = embeddings[SOS_token]
    decoder_input=Variable(torch.from_numpy(decoder_input)).cuda()
    decoder_hidden = (decoder.initHidden(),decoder.initHidden())
        for di in range(target_length):
            decoder_output, decoder_hidden = decoder(decoder_input.view(1,batch_size,-1), decoder_hidden)
```

I get he following error:

> Expected hidden[0] size (1, 1, 300), got (1, 50, 300)

What am I missing in order to make the model expect batched hidden states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the `LSTM`, the flag `batch_first` is not necessary, because it assumes a different shape of your input. From the docs:

> If True, then the input and output tensors are provided as (batch,
>   seq, feature). Default: False

change the LSTM creation to:

```
self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=embedding_size, num_layers=1, hidden_size=hidden_size)
```

Also, there is a type error. When you create the `decoder_input` using `torch.from_numpy()` it has a `dtype=torch.float64`, while `decoder_input` has as default `dtype=torch.float32`. Change the line where you create the `decoder_input` to something like

```
decoder_input = Variable(torch.from_numpy(decoder_input)).cuda().float()
```

With both changes, it is supposed to work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

change .view() to reflect [1,batch size, embedding_size] as the first dimension.

also, you don't need to initialize a zero tensor, pytorch uses a zero tensor if no tensors are provided as an initial tensor.

Comment: Thanks, but when I remove the batch_first flag, I get the following error, suggesting that it still assumes batch size is none from what I understand: 177 if batch_sizes is None: 178 result = _impl(input, hx, self._flat_weights, self.bias, self.num_layers, --> 179 self.dropout, self.training, self.bidirectional, self.batch_first) 180 else: 181 result = _impl(input, batch_sizes, hx, self._flat_weights, self.bias, RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM

Comment: you could even try removing batch_first=True and setting the .view(1, -1, embedding_dim)